# Removing attributes with colons with BeautifulSoup Python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I sometimes run into html with has weird attributes, like for example **fb:share:layout**.

```
<a class="addthis_button_facebook_share" fb:share:layout="button_count" style="height:20px;"></a>
```

Im not entirely sure what they are called (itemscopes? namespaces?).

Currently I parse HTML with beautifulsoup4 in python. Im wondering if there is a way to remove or rename all attributes that contain these colons.

Thanks

**EDIT:**
Thanks for the answer. I ended up implementing it like this:

```
    for tag in soup.find_all(True):
            attrs = dict(tag.attrs)
            for attr in attrs:
                if ":" in attr:
                    del tag.attrs[attr]
```

Comment: Whats your goal? What data are you after?

Comment: Beautiful Soup stores the tag attributes in a dictionary. So you can delete this attribute with `del tag['fb:share:layout']`.

Comment: @heemayl Im not really after any data. Im just looking for a way to remove all attributes which contain these colons...

Comment: why delete them?

Comment: @QHarr I need to pass it to another service that will crash if any of these tags are contained in the HTML file

Comment: Aha. Hadn’t thought of that!

Comment: You don't need regex for finding the colon. Strings are iterables, so you can do `if ':' in attr` which is a lot faster. Even better: `if ':' in set(attr)`.

Comment: @BramVanroy Oh yes I forgot about that. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

def _remove_attrs(soup):
    tag_list = soup.findAll(lambda tag: len(tag.attrs) > 0)
    for t in tag_list:
        for attr, val in t.attrs:
            del t[attr]
    return soup


def example():
    doc = '<html><head><title>test</title></head><body id="foo"><p class="whatever">junk</p><div style="background: yellow;">blah</div></body></html>'
    print 'Before:\n%s' % doc
    soup = BeautifulSoup(doc)
    clean_soup = _remove_attrs(soup)
    print 'After:\n%s' % clean_soup
```

You can also try this below for extra refernce.

> Remove all HTML attributes with BeautifulSoup except some tags( ...)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# remove all attributes
def _remove_all_attrs(soup):
    for tag in soup.find_all(True): 
        tag.attrs = {}
    return soup

# remove all attributes except some tags
def _remove_all_attrs_except(soup):
    whitelist = ['a','img']
    for tag in soup.find_all(True):
        if tag.name not in whitelist:
            tag.attrs = {}
    return soup

# remove all attributes except some tags(only saving ['href','src'] attr)
def _remove_all_attrs_except_saving(soup):
    whitelist = ['a','img']
    for tag in soup.find_all(True):
        if tag.name not in whitelist:
            tag.attrs = {}
        else:
            attrs = dict(tag.attrs)
            for attr in attrs:
                if attr not in ['src','href']:
                    del tag.attrs[attr]
    return soup
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes thanks a lot. I ended up implementing it like this:
```
    for tag in soup.find_all(True):
            attrs = dict(tag.attrs)
            for attr in attrs:
                if re.search(":",attr):
                    del tag.attrs[attr]
```